# Server is not recognising users passwords

Tags: linux

Our Red Hat Linux server is having problems logging established users onto the network! There was a proxy server problem the previous day and the proxy setting was changed? Any Ideas what could be happening. The night before it work and then in the morning half of the users couldn't log on?

Comment: How are these users signing into the server? SSH? Console? VNC? Anything in your `/var/log/secure` log?

Comment: No I don't think so? Their signing in via Windows Xp computers. Either via the LAN or Wireless. There was an smb return error message on the server other than that I could not find any other reason.

Answer (score 0):

Then you should first try to check what kind of error does the `smbclient` return, use:

```
smbclient -L //localhost -U valid-user
```

on server.

If this doesn't give you any clues about the problem, check logs, to find where they are placed do the following:

```
$ grep '\<log\>' /etc/samba/smb.conf
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        log level = 2
```

check the generic log file (in this example `/var/log/samba/log.smbd`) and then machine specific file (`/var/log/samba/log.samba-server-name`)